# Web page mobile-friendly

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I am working on making a web page mobile-friendly.
I read that the first thing I should do is setting the viewport.
So this is what I did. The result is better in some respects, but not all.
Here is my current problem:
While the text now appears with fonts much easier to read than before. The images got rescaled in too large proportions. I had about 8 pictures aligned horizontally (on a computer display). When displayed on a mobile, without viewport, it would appear resized (all 8 pictures on one line) and look too small. But with viewport, it appears one picture per line, each one being a bit too large. I wish I could keep the text display as it is, but make the pictures displayed 4 (or 3) per line. How can I do that?

Comment: check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Setting the viewport is not a magic bullet that can automagically turn your desktop-only codebase into a perfectly functional responsive website. If your website wasn't coded with mobile/responsive in mind, then there's probably quite a lot properties you'll need to override/redefine using [Media Queries](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/). It also goes without saying that we can't help you solve your problem if you don't provide any code.

Comment: No problem I am aware of that. At this point I am only trying to see how things fit together. Now testing this @media stuff and see what it does. My first trials didn't have any whatsoever effects, I need to dig more.

Comment: In addition to media queries, you should work with relative size. If you want to display 4 pictures/line for mobile instead of 8 for desktop, the best way would be to use percentage: set your pictures width to 25% in your media queries.